# Estimate the average time when the value of a given parameter is increasing

Tags: java

There is the following array `track` which indicates the increase of some parameter. Each row refers to 5 days:

```
[0] 5
[1] 10
[2] 12
[3] 11
[4] 7
[5] 6
[6] 10
[7] 15
[8] 16
```

I need to estimate the average time when the parameter is increasing. In this example, from [0] to [2], and from [5] to [8]. The answer must be:

```
Period 1 (from [0] to [2]) = 5+5+5 = 15 days. 
Period 2 (from [5] to [8]) = 20 days 
ANSWER = (15 + 20)/2 = 17.5 days
```

I wrote the following code. But it fails because `curr` is > than `track.length` at the last iteration. How can I solve this issue?

```
    private double getAvgGrowingTime(double[] track)
    {
        List<Double> timeList = new ArrayList<Double>();

        double temptime = 0.0;
        boolean stop = false;
        int curr = 1;
        while (curr < track.length)
        {
            while (track[curr]>track[curr-1])
            {
                temptime += 5;
                stop = false;
                curr++;
            }
            if (!stop)
                timeList.add(temptime);
            temptime = 0.0;
            stop = true;
            curr++;
        }

//...

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the inner while to this:

```
while ( curr< track.length && track[curr]>track[curr-1])
{
     temptime += 5;
     stop = false;
     curr++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. (curr< track.length && track[curr]>track[curr-1]) works fine. I have used (track[curr]>track[curr-1] && curr< track.length) ...:(

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- When you have data like 5, 10, 15 your output will be 10 which you need 15.
- You will run ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException using above example since it will go in your inner while loop and wont have check on current index with number of elements in track.

To resolve both of your issues, you could do something like:

```
boolean first = true;
while (curr < track.length) {
    while (curr < track.length && track[curr] > track[curr - 1]) {
         if (curr == 1 && first) {
             temptime += 5;
             first = false;
         }
```